# Kotlin nested class members visibility

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin, I tried to have a nested NestedClass inside the SomeClass class, have a NestedClass instance, and have a member inside the NestedClass so that only SomeClass can access that member. I have tried the following

```
class SomeCLass {
    class NestedClass(private var member: Int)
    val nInstance = NestedClass(4)

    fun doSomething() {
        nInstance.member = 10
    }
}
```

but the member is inaccessible from SomeClass. In general, I want to have two classes, and only the first class should be able to access the member of the second class. How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Because private members of the inner/ nested class are not accessible to the outer class in kotlin. see [discussion](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/why-outer-class-cannot-see-private-members-of-inner-class/6791). You can remove the private visibility modifier from `member` to make it accessible to the outer class.

Comment: If I remove the private visibility `member` will be accessible from anywhere.

Comment: Yes, after removing the private visibility modifier, you can access `member` from anywhere. But note, nested classes are static by default in Kotlin, so you have to use them accordingly.

Comment: Just as a side note, you could use the `internal` modifier if you wanted it to be private outside of your module.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your inner class private instead of making a private property:

```
class SomeCLass {
    private class NestedClass(var member: Int)
    private val nInstance = NestedClass(4)

    fun doSomething() {
        nInstance.member = 10
    }
}
```